# is there a better way to show loading message with jquery ui tabs?

Tags: ajax, loading, jquery-ui-tabs

using [jquery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax), when you load a tab in ajax, the tab changes message to say "Loading . ." i think this is a little subtle.

Is there anyway you can do something in this content area of the tab [similar to what block ui does when you are loading a call in ajax.](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)

Comment: 'similar to blockUI' or 'using blockUI'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would display a loading message within the content area like so (untested):

```
$('#selector').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {

    // show default $.blockUI loading message
    $('ui.panel').blockUI();
}).bind('tabsload', function(event, ui) {

    // remove loading message
    $('ui.panel').unblockUI();
});
```